# Plotly Dash is it possible generate callback inside the code

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to generate callback only if the Queue is not empty.
Now I am checking if the Queue is not empty using Interval callback.

```
@app.callback(Output('signal', 'data'),
              Input('interval', 'n_intervals'))
def signal_output(n):

    if not app_queue.empty():
        res = app_queue.get()

        # I would like to generate new callback here to update graphs
        return (res, )
    return ({},)
```

**Is it possible to generate a callback inside the `if` statement?**

Comment: I don't think having a callback inside a callback is possible. You could add additional Outputs to this callback to update your graphs.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve vs a standard callback that simply does `raise no_update` when the queue is empty?

Comment: @coralvanda I can check the queue status using *Interval* callbacks. But I want update the page element (e.g. graph) only if new data is available (not on every *Interval* callback). I almost haven't  experience with plotly-dash yet.

Comment: I think you could use the `no_update` thing for the same result. Hook up the callback to the interval, and just use that when there's no new data to update with. The page won't re-render or change the graph.

Comment: @coralvanda thank you! I will try this.